# ajax.js keyup function not activating while in the tutorial it works fabulously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have search engine that works except for this keyup function.As user types an input it should display the words(ex if I type a, then search bar should show the results that starts with a)but this function isn't working. I have to type all the words then enter to get the result. I went back to jquery tutorial for this but I still don't understand. Thank you in advance.

This is my js code.

```
$(function(){

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/",
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    });

});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

Then to call this code I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

And I have more in my index html

```
<h3>Search</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" />

<ul id="search-results">

</ul>
```

With this code, nothing shows up. 
but inside my search.html search engine works and here's the code

```
<form method="get" action=".">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="search">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {% if query %}
        <h3>result</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.name }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>no result</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

please ignore any {} code up there as they are django. my question is how do I use the jquery function to work in either index or search.html? my goal was to use search engine in index page but it just won't work so I want to use keyup function in my search.html///thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your binding method ever get called in a `onload` function or anything?
If not, I would suggest doing so. If your are not comfortable to set the binding on the page load, you can add the handler to the html-tag directly:

```
function handle_keyup() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search/",
            data: { 
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });

    }
```

and in your template:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" onkeyup="handle_keyup()"/>
```

Comment: thanks for another post Remi, but I'm not sure what you mean up there. are you able to chat right now?

Comment: oh shoot I have to have at least 20 reputations to be able to chat, can we do this through gmail?they have online chat system too

Comment: my email is rladudrb111@gmail.com

Comment: hello are you there?

Comment: hello I sent you an invite on gmail chat

Comment: can you help me with one little thing (last thing I need to deploy), the feature works but ajax part is falling apart///if you read this please let me know...the last feature almost works but has some problem which I'm fighiting for a while